# ActiveAdmin: Sort by association (belongs_to)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

I have an index admin view where I'm displaying an associated model `City`.  I'd like to be able to sort by city name, but when I click the column header to sort I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Admin/deals#index

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: cities.name: SELECT  "deals".* FROM "deals"  ORDER BY cities.name desc LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
```

Index view

```
ActiveAdmin.register Deal do
  index do
     column :id
     column :city
  end
  ...
end
```

Model

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
end
```

How can I sort by city?

Answer (score 2):

With Rails 3 or 4:

```
index do
  column :city, :sortable=>:"cities.name"

  ...
end
```

And then, in the same file, you need this so that the `Deal` queries include the `City` attributes:

```
controller do
  def scoped_collection
    Deal.includes(:city)
  end

  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/pull/623#issuecomment-2419393 and the following comments. You have to tell activeadmin how to do the sorting - probably something like `column :city, :sortable => 'cities.name'` and define a `joined` scope before you define the deals index page. Something like

```
scope :joined, :default => true do |deals|
  deals.includes [:city]
end
```

Comment: unfortunately, it brakes if you try to use it with filtering