# ActiveAdmin sort by nested association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am having trouble sorting by an association of an association.

I have a Student, who is in a School, which is in a City.  I want to be able to sort users alphabetically by city name.

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  belongs_to :school
```

and

```
class School < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  belongs_to :city
```

and

```
class City < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  validates: name, presence: true
```

How can I make a column on the Students page which shows the City name, can be sorted by the city name, and the ActiveAdmin link uses the city ID as the link parameter?

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266498/activeadmin-sort-by-association-belongs-to) is a good starting point. You should be able to extend the include with something like:

```
def scoped_collection
  Student.includes(school: [:city])
end
```

which I think should allow `sortable: cities.name`